# Remove query from search input still displays results on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a home page where I display search results from `searchContext`. Here is my `home page` code.

```
import { useSearch } from "./SearchContext";

const Home = () => {
  const { isLoading, search, searchResult } = useSearch();
  const startIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * searchResult.length - 5);

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Home page</h3>
      {isLoading ? (
        <h1>LOADING...</h1>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <div>Search value: {search}</div>
          {searchResult.slice(startIndex, startIndex + 5).map((el) => (
            <li key={el.id}>{el.title}</li>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Here is my `searchContext`.

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useContext, useState } from "react";

export const SearchContext = createContext({
  isLoading: false,
  search: "",
  searchResult: [],
  setSearch: () => {}
});

export const useSearch = () => useContext(SearchContext);

const SearchProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const searchNews = async () => {
      console.log(search);
      setIsLoading(true);
      const news = await fetchNews(search, 15, 1);
      setItems(news);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    const fetchNews = async (section, pageSize, page) => {
      // const url = `${baseUrl}${section}?page-size=${pageSize}&page=${page}&api-key=${apiKey}`;
      const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
      const news = await fetch(url);
      return await news.json();
    };
    if (search.length > 0) { // I added this condition so that searchNews is not called when search is empty.
      searchNews();
    } // Here I can add an else statement and call `setItems([])` to set empty array to items but it does not work either.
  }, [search]);

  return (
    <SearchContext.Provider
      value={{
        isLoading,
        search,
        searchResult: items,
        setSearch: (e) => setSearch(e.target.value)
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </SearchContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default SearchProvider;
```

This context is keep calling `searchNews` when I enter text to `input field`. This works fine for searching and displaying results. But when I remove `search string` from `input field` then I do not want this to show or retrieve any more result from API call. Now this works if I slowly remove `search string` from `input field`. But when I remove `search string` faster and quicker then `items` still has result and it shows those result on `home page`. I do not want this. I want when the `search input` is empty then I do not want to show any `search result` on `home page` or any page.

To solve this I added an if condition in `searchContext` which checks if the `search` is not empty which means the `input field` is not empty then call `searchNews` method and load results from API but if it is empty then do not call `searchNews` anymore which should not display `search result` on any page.

Here is the search.js page with search input field.

```
import { useSearch } from "./SearchContext";

const Search = () => {
  const { setSearch } = useSearch();

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="search"
        placeholder="Enter search term"
        onChange={setSearch}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

How can I fix this problem when I removed search string faster and quicker?

Here is the code sandbox for this problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/replace-search-current-page-contents-with-search-contents-forked-x4l0o?file=/src/SearchContext.js

Comment: How about using Debounce? https://codesandbox.io/s/replace-search-current-page-contents-with-search-contents-forked-4mbrs?file=/src/SearchContext.js

Comment: @PsyGik I checked you sandbox it is still displaying results using debounce.

Comment: @Om3ga please chek my updated answer. i guess this is what you want

Comment: I don't get it. `fetchNews(search.length ? search : "news", 15, 1);` tells that if no seach terms are present, fetch with the default term viz `news`. But you don't want to display the default search results either?

Comment: There is shouldn't be that condition. It should be `fetchNews(search, 15, 1);`  basically. I updated the sandbox.

Comment: with this updated sandbox then you need to store 2 lists. you cant "restore" to home page without refetching data if you jus store items in one list.

Comment: Updated Sandbox to clear items when there are no search terms. https://codesandbox.io/s/replace-search-current-page-contents-with-search-contents-forked-4mbrs?file=/src/SearchContext.js

Comment: Basically in debounce you are using `setTimeout()` function which I already tried before posting this question here. It did not work for me. Secondly, I am refetching data for home page when the searchResult is empty but still I get contents from search query not for home page contents.

Comment: I already added comment in my code in the post above then I also tried else statement to set `setItems` back to empty array which didn't work either. This is for code `if (!debouncedSearchTerm) {
        setItems([]);
        return;
      }` in you updated sandbox.

Comment: @PsyGik  however, when I add setTimeout is shows home page contents for a brief period then it is replaced back with searchResult contents.

Comment: Okay, so let me understand. 1. Your search should work when user enters something; 2. When the search input is cleared, the results must be emptied; 3. You have a logic (not posted here) which will trigger search for homepage. For #1 and #2, my (updated) Sandbox works well.

Comment: i think when search is cleared, he needs to fetch home page data

Comment: When search is empty then it should fetch data for `home page` which is basically residing in `localstorage`. When I use `setTimeout` it delays getting data for `searchResult`. During that delay `searchResult` is populated with `home page` contents which is correct but when `setTimeout callback` is called it again fetching information for `search query` which again populates the `searchResult` with search query which is basically empty.

Comment: I see, check the updated Sandbox where `searchNews` takes an arg viz `debouncedSearchTerm` if user enters something, else defaults to `news` (viz what I assume is from localStorage).

Comment: @PsyGik I updated my code in the post and in sandbox. It no longer send request to default `news`. It always send request to `search` term.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the event you are handling, the on change event is ideal for the select element while the input element needs the oninput event.
Try changing the onchange event with oninput event

Answer (score 0):

When we create any autocomplete components, we need to take into consideration user's typing speed, and whether per letter search is warrant for such a scenario (which most probably not).

Hence we can learn to use debounce, or setTimeout to create a slight delay, while waiting for input, before we do the fetch.

In this example, create a global variable `timer` which resides ***OUTSIDE*** the component, so it doesn't get called/resetted on every render.

```
let timer; //outside component


const mycomponent = () => {

.....

  useEffect(() => {
    const searchNews = async () => {

      setIsLoading(true);
      clearTimeout(timer) //clear timer on every call
      timer = setTimeout(() => { //recreate a timer to call the fetch in 100ms
          const news = await fetchNews(search.length ? search : "news", 15, 1);
          setItems(news);
          setIsLoading(false); //need to add try /catch 
      }, 100) //<--- call the function in 100 ms

    };
if (search.length > 0) {
  searchNews();
} else {
  setItems([]);
}
    .............
  }, [search]); 
}
```

We will create the timer, and reset the timer with clearTimeout(timer) on each input. Once the user *pauses* typing, you will perform the fetch.

PS: can increase the delay of 100ms to improve performance. I'm using 200ms and it works well for my backend which returns results in less than 100 ms.

Comment: When I add `setTimeout` is shows home page contents for a brief period then it is replaced back with searchResult contents.

Comment: what's the difference with home page content vs searchResult content? The logic I see in your original post only shows search results

Comment: do note the setTimeout function only fetches result, your rendering logic is separated and you should be looking into that separately.

Comment: I use searchResult for both searching items and fetching information for home page items. homepage contents come from localstorage.

Comment: Is it because of your `search.length ?` check? In your code you have decided to fetch "news" when your search input is empty. If you want to show your home page content then remove the request for "news" when search input is empty. In fact you should be removing this `search.length` logic totally in your context. If you want to display "news" by default you can use `setSearch("news")` in your homepage component.

Comment: I fixed that part in the code and updated the question also. It should not make request to `news` it should always make request to `search` query. But it is also making request to empty search query.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/replace-search-current-page-contents-with-search-contents-forked-n9yxg?file=/src/SearchContext.js - Does this work like how it should?

Comment: No, if you read my comments on this post and comments in the code in this post above you will find out that I already used else statement to setItems to empty array which didn't work either.

Comment: No, if you read my comments on this post and comments in the code in this post above you will find out that I already used else statement to setItems to empty array which didn't work either.

Comment: No, if you read my comments on this post and comments in the code in this post above you will find out that I already used else statement to setItems to empty array which didn't work either.

Comment: my question is. Can u check my sandbox? Does it work like how you want it to be? I intentionally show a red box when your array is empty